# I want to get rid of all the special characters like [(' and im really stuck in how to

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sqlite

```
def trackItems():
    cursor.execute("SELECT ItemsBought, COUNT(*) FROM Purchase GROUP BY ItemsBought")
    stock = []
    Graphs = cursor.fetchall()
    print(Graphs)
    separator = " "
    f = open("Stock.txt", "w")

    values = ','.join([str(i) for i in Graphs])
    f.write(values)
```

Output

('DONT', 1),('MY', 2),('PLEASE', 2)

How can i get rid of opening and closing brackets and all the quotation marks. If anyone could help, it would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace substrings from a string with "" (so it will remove it) using str.replace(substring, "") e.g.

```
    "(abcd(.ad".replace("(", "") #output: abcd.ad
```

Then you can just write this string to the file.
Code:

```
    def trackItems():
        cursor.execute("SELECT ItemsBought, COUNT(*) FROM Purchase GROUP BY ItemsBought")
        stock = []
        Graphs = cursor.fetchall()
        print(Graphs)
        separator = " "
        f = open("Stock.txt", "w")
        values = ','.join([str(i) for i in Graphs]).replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace("'", "")
        f.write(values)
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than thinking about this as a problem about special characters, think about it as flattening a sequence (list) of subsequences (tuples, the rows) into a list of individual elements, which can then be `joined`.

You could do this with a `for` loop:

```py
 >>> flattened = []
>>> for row in Graphs:
...     flattened.extend(row)
... 
>>> flattened
['DONT', 1, 'MY', 2, 'PLEASE', 2]
```

but a list comprehension is more idiomatic

```py
>>> Graphs = [('DONT', 1),('MY', 2),('PLEASE', 2)]
>>> values = ','.join([str(i) for j in Graphs for i in j])
>>> print(values)
DONT,1,MY,2,PLEASE,2
```